# How to prevent pane from listening mouse events which are dedicated to children nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I have Pane container and several children of this container which are lines. I also have Event Handler for a Line:

```
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> lineOnMouseClicked = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("Line has been clicked");
    }
};
```

The problem is that I also need Event Handler on pane like this:

```
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> paneOnMouseClicked = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("Pane Clicked");
    }
};
```

What I want: if I click on a Line then lineOnMouseClicked need to be invoke, and only the EventHandler, not with paneOnMouseClicked.

In my situation, when I click on a line, both of them invokes.

I've done some research, but, unfortunately, didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consume event in line:

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> lineOnMouseClicked = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
        System.out.println("Line has been clicked");
        t.consume(); // consume event -> no further propagation
    }
};


line.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, lineOnMouseClicked);
pane.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, paneOnMouseClicked);
```